# How to convert list of nested dictionary into Pandas dataframe. But nested dictionary list length is not same for every key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want convert the nested dictionary list  into data frame. but Nested dictionary each key's List has different length. for instance, the below nested dictionary keys  `x's`,`y's`,`z's` list has different lengths.

```
dict_example = {
    'a': {
        'x': ['f1', 'f2', 'f6'],
        'y': ['f6', 'f9', 'f2', 'f8'],
        'z': ['f1', 'f9', 'f2', 'f8', 'f6', 'f10', 'f3']
    },
    'b': {
        'x': ['f1', 'f2', 'f6', 'f4'],
        'y': ['f6', 'f9', 'f2', 'f8', 'f17','f12'],
        'z': ['f1', 'f9', 'f2', 'f10', 'f3']
    }
}
```

```py
from tabulate import tabulate
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dict([ (k,pd.Series(v)) for k,v in dict_example.items()]))
print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))
```

the above code is giving the output like the below table. But i want to get the each  value of the list into a row that belongs to nested key. key `a` and `b` are  main columns.

```
+----+---------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|    | a                                           | b                               |
|----+---------------------------------------------+---------------------------------|
| x  | ['f1', 'f2', 'f6']                          | ['f1', 'f2', 'f6', 'f4']        |
| y  | ['f6', 'f9', 'f2', 'f8']                    | ['f6', 'f9', 'f2', 'f8', 'f17'] |
| z  | ['f1', 'f9', 'f2', 'f8', 'f6', 'f10', 'f3'] | ['f1', 'f9', 'f2', 'f10', 'f3'] |
+----+---------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

The output data frame should look like this:

```
    a   b
x   f1  f1
    f2  f2
    f6  f6
    NaN f4
y   f6  f6
    f9  f9
    f2  f2
    f8  f8
    NaN f17
z   f1  f1
    f9  f9
    f2  f2
    f8  f10
    f6  f3
    f10 NaN
    f3  NaN
```

Comment: Can you post the specific output you want for `dict_example`?

Comment: @timgeb, I did. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use dict comprehension with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
d = {k: pd.DataFrame({k1:pd.Series(v1) for k1, v1 in v.items()}) 
                      for k,v in dict_example.items()}

df = pd.concat(d, axis=1).stack()
print (df)
       a    b
x 0   f1   f1
  1   f2   f2
  2   f6   f6
  3  NaN   f4
y 0   f6   f6
  1   f9   f9
  2   f2   f2
  3   f8   f8
  4  NaN  f17
  5  NaN  f12
z 0   f1   f1
  1   f9   f9
  2   f2   f2
  3   f8  f10
  4   f6   f3
  5  f10  NaN
  6   f3  NaN
```

Comment: ValueError: columns must have matching element counts. you are getting the same error that i have faced.

Comment: nope, it's wrong.

Comment: @rk___ - what means wrong?